# How do I express this logic?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to incorporate bottom logic here.

**If mrn is not null**, trigger "guard clause" saying 'if length of FirstName is less than 3, "Please specify.." and if length of LastName is less than 3, "Please specify..".

I am struggling regards to If statement logic as well as how to express "reRender" correctly on apex:commandButton as well as applying into apex:pageBlockSection (id="msgs?) on the bottom after commandButton.

I think logic got mixed up with mrn, lname and fname.

Here is my updated Apex and VF code:

```
public with sharing class psw {
    public String sfprn { get; set; }
    public String mrn {get;set;}
    public String lname {get;set;}
    public String fname {get;set;}


public class TableRow2{
    public String sfprn {get;set;}
    public String mrn {get;set;}
    public String lname {get;set;}
    public String fname {get;set;}
    public Decimal SurveySelection {get;set;}
}

public List<TableRow2> RowList {get; set;}

public PageReference searchPatients(){

    RowList = new List<TableRow2>();
    TableRow2 tr;

    if (mrn == null )
    { 
        if (lname != null && lname.length() < 3)
        {
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
           ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please specify at least three characters of Last Name'
        ));
        return null;
        }

        if (fname != null && fname.length() < 3)
        {
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
           ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please specify at least three characters of First Name'
        ));
        return null;
        }                   
    }

    String bind_fname = string.isBlank(fName) || fname.length() <3 ? null : (fname.left(3) + '%');
    String bind_lname = string.isBlank(lname) || lname.length() <3 ? null : (lname.left(3) + '%');

    for(Patient__c con : [SELECT sfprn__c, 
                                mrn__c,
                                LName__c, 
                                FName__c,
                                (select SurveySelection__c.SurveySelection__c from SurveySelections__r) 
                                FROM Patient__c
                                where ( mrn__c =:mrn )
             or ( LName__c LIKE :bind_lname and FName__c LIKE :bind_fname ) LIMIT 1                       
                                ]){                                    
        tr = new TableRow2();
        tr.sfprn = con.sfprn__c;
        tr.mrn = con.mrn__c;
        tr.lname = con.LName__c;
        tr.fname = con.FName__c;
        tr.SurveySelection = con.SurveySelections__r.isEmpty() ? null : con.SurveySelections__r[0].SurveySelection__c;

        RowList.add(tr);         

        }
     return null;   
} 

}
```

---

```
<apex:page Controller="psw" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <!-- Search button-->
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <!-- Added 5/30 -->   
        <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"></apex:pageMessages> 

        <!-- Modified 5/30 -->
        <!--<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchPatients}" reRender="contact-table"/>  -->
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchPatients}" reRender="msgs"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <!-- Modified 5/30 -->
    <!--        
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="contact-table" columns="1">  -->
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="msgs" columns="1">
        <!-- Input starts -->
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="MRN" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!mrn}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!lname}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="First Name" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!fname}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        <!-- Input ends -->

        <!-- Output 1 starts --->
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">MRN</apex:facet>
                {!c.mrn}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Last Name</apex:facet>
                {!c.lname}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">First Name</apex:facet>
                {!c.fname}
            </apex:column>                         
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <!-- Output 1 ends --->  
     </apex:pageBlockSection>       
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it on the controller side, you would use `ApexPages.addMessage`. You'll need to add an early return in this case (called a "guard clause") so that you don't process the rest of your logic. This sort of validation would look roughly like:

```
if (fname != null || fname.length() < 3)
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please specify at least three characters'
    ));
    return null;
}
// same for last name
```

You'll need to rerender an `<apex:pageMessages>` element in order to display these errors. Your markup changes would look roughly like:

```
<apex:page ...>

    <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />

    <!-- intermediate markup -->

    <apex:commandButton ... rerender="msgs" />

    <!-- other markup -->

</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is good stuff.  Thanks. I was able to add that, but I am getting logical error with "IF" statement of other variable (mrn).  How do I incorporate this into VF as id points to "msgs"? I updated my codes.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to check if the length is less than 3 as well:

```
String bind_fname = string.isBlank(fName) || fName.length() < 3 ? 
    null : (fname.left(3) + '%');
```